# How to export texture mapping to 3dsMax

Tags: export, texture-coordinates

If I try to export an object to 3ds, everything seems to work fine except the texture's mapping. How could i fix that ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some part of the model is good in the second picture. May be it has multiple materials and/or UVMaps and something missing after the export or assigned in wrong order.

Comment: thanks for your answer. there is indeed actually a lot of different material on my object (i specify the whole city however is one single mesh) but i don't know if it is possible to merge them

Comment: Did you try other format for example fbx?

Comment: yes i have tried fbx, obj and collada without sucess (same issues)